# Get EOFException while reading serialized object in Java

Tags: java, serialization, serializable, eofexception

I have two methods, one that serialize the Object, and it works ok:

```
public void record()throws RecordingException
    {
        ObjectOutputStream outputStream = null;
        try
        {
            outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("src/data/employee.dat"));
            outputStream.writeObject(this);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new RecordingException(ex);
        } catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new RecordingException(ex);
        }finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (outputStream != null) outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ex){}
        }
    }
```

The problem here when deserializing the object, I get EOFException!:

```
public final User loadObject(UserType usertype) throws InvalidLoadObjectException
    {
        ObjectInputStream istream = null;
        String path = null;
        if (usertype == UserType.EMPLOYEE)
        {
            path = "data/employee.dat";
        }else if (usertype == UserType.CUSTOMER)
        {
            path = "data/customer.dat";
        }else
            throw new InvalidLoadObjectException("Object is not a sub class of User");

        try 
        {
            istream = new ObjectInputStream(ObjectLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path));             

            User u = loadObject(istream);
            istream.close();
            return u;
        }catch (EOFException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new InvalidLoadObjectException(ex);
        }
    }

private User loadObject(ObjectInputStream stream) throws InvalidLoadObjectException
    {
        try
        {
            return (User) stream.readObject();
        } catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new InvalidLoadObjectException(ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new InvalidLoadObjectException(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does customer.dat contain User objects?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the cause of your problem, but the code that writes the file has a subtle flaw.  In the `finally` block, you close the stream and *ignore any exceptions*.  If the `close()` method performs a final `flush()`, then any exceptions thrown in the flush will go unreported.

Answer (score 0):

Try `outputStream.flush()` before closing your stream in serialization object.

Comment: That won't make any difference. close() calls flush(). See the Javadoc.

Answer (score -1):

The file was empty, or didn't contain the full serialization of the object.